# Does HTMLStripCharFilterFactory @ Solr 3.4 strip out html for returned fields?

Tags: solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfsearch, cfindex

I'm using CF10 which should be using Solr 3.4 according to corporatezen.com/2013/11/updating-solr-engine-coldfusion. I added `<charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>` to `<fieldType name="text">` but the summary field in the search result still includes HTML. Any idea why?

`<field name="summary"   type="text"   indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" />`

http://localhost:8985/solr/test/admin/schema.jsp shows:

> Field: summary Field Type: TEXT
>
> Properties: Tokenized, Stored
>
> Schema: Tokenized, Stored
>
> Position Increment Gap: 100
>
> Index Analyzer: org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain DETAILS
>
> Char Filters:
>
> org.apache.solr.analysis.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory
>   args:{luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 } Tokenizer Class:
>   org.apache.solr.analysis.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory
>
> Filters:
>
> org.apache.solr.analysis.StopFilterFactory args:{words: stopwords.txt
>   ignoreCase: true enablePositionIncrements: true luceneMatchVersion:
>   LUCENE_24 } org.apache.solr.analysis.WordDelimiterFilterFactory
>   args:{splitOnCaseChange: 1 generateNumberParts: 1 catenateWords: 1
>   luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 generateWordParts: 1 catenateAll: 0
>   catenateNumbers: 1 } org.apache.solr.analysis.LowerCaseFilterFactory
>   args:{luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 }
>   org.apache.solr.analysis.EnglishPorterFilterFactory args:{protected:
>   protwords.txt luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 }
>   org.apache.solr.analysis.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory
>   args:{luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 } Query Analyzer:
>   org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain DETAILS
>
> Char Filters:
>
> org.apache.solr.analysis.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory
>   args:{luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 } Tokenizer Class:
>   org.apache.solr.analysis.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory
>
> Filters:
>
> org.apache.solr.analysis.SynonymFilterFactory args:{synonyms:
>   synonyms.txt expand: true ignoreCase: true luceneMatchVersion:
>   LUCENE_24 } org.apache.solr.analysis.StopFilterFactory args:{words:
>   stopwords.txt ignoreCase: true luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 }
>   org.apache.solr.analysis.WordDelimiterFilterFactory
>   args:{splitOnCaseChange: 1 generateNumberParts: 1 catenateWords: 0
>   luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 generateWordParts: 1 catenateAll: 0
>   catenateNumbers: 0 } org.apache.solr.analysis.LowerCaseFilterFactory
>   args:{luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 }
>   org.apache.solr.analysis.EnglishPorterFilterFactory args:{protected:
>   protwords.txt luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 }
>   org.apache.solr.analysis.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory
>   args:{luceneMatchVersion: LUCENE_24 }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to differentiate between the stored and the indexed. The filter you have added to the field will alter the tokens that are stored in Solr's index, for searching, but not the stored values for display.

Solr keeps two versions of a field*. One is the stored one. This is the original portion of text, in your case *with* HTML included. The other one is the index version. There the whole magic of text analysis has been applied.

Then when you perform a search, the index is used to look up which documents have created a match. When displaying the result, the stored version is presented to you.

---

* Of course only in case that you turned on `stored="true"` and `indexed="true"`.

Comment: Thank you! I turned the field to stored="true" and indexed="true" and I'm still getting html markup returned to me. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to express. Solr will not clean up the stored values. All that analysis will clean up the indexed tokens, but not the stored text that is to be displayed.

Comment: So how do you strip the HTML from the stored text?

Comment: That depends on how you hand documents over to Solr (your import route). Within that importhandler you can do something like that

Comment: @jimcollins, if you're using ColdFusion as in the OP, then you can use `REReplace()` to strip HTML tags when adding or updating the collection.

Comment: @DavidFaber how would I use ReReplace() in a cfindex tag?

Comment: That's a good question! I don't think you could. But then I recommend using Solr's web service to index your data rather than using `<cfindex>`. See the following link (admittedly old) for some guidance on how that might be accomplished: http://www.thefaberfamily.org/search-smith/2011/12/coldfusion-9-indexing-custom-fields-in-solr/